# local server not populating ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a local db.json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "project_topics": [
"- Any -",
"Access for disadvantaged",
"Agriculture, forestry and fisheries",
"Animal welfare",
"Energy and resources",
"Enhance social inclusion, equal opportunities and participation in sports",
"Enterprise, industry and SMEs (incl. entrepreneurship)",
"Entrepreneurial learning - entrepreneurship education",
"Environment and climate change" 
]}
```

I want to populate input with ng-repeat and I do it like so:

```
<label class="item item-select " id="findYourProject-select3">
            <span class="input-label">type of project</span>
            <select ng-repeat="topic in project_topics"></select>
        </label>
```

The input is not being populated. What should I consider?

Comment: I copied a wrong segment of the code. I updated my question.

Comment: use `ng-options` http://jsfiddle.net/2JWb2/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give ng-repeat for `options` not `select`

see the plunker json from external file http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.data = {
  "project_topics": [
"- Any -",
"Access for disadvantaged",
"Agriculture, forestry and fisheries",
"Animal welfare",
"Energy and resources",
"Enhance social inclusion, equal opportunities and participation in sports",
"Enterprise, industry and SMEs (incl. entrepreneurship)",
"Entrepreneurial learning - entrepreneurship education",
"Environment and climate change" 
]};
       /* var urlPath = 'db.json';
      $http.get(urlPath).then(function(response) {
       $scope.data = response.data;
       
      }, function(error) {
       
      });*/
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <select  ng-model="singleSelect">
     <option  ng-repeat="topic in data.project_topics">{{topic}}</option>
    </select>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: This approach is clearly working, but I want my data to be in a db.json file and not in my controller

Comment: see the commented code from above code, it will work for external json file

Comment: @NewLuckyProgramer see the updated answer , plunker code created , data loading from external json file

Comment: Rejs, I made it working by hard coding the options in the controller. When I get permition to the online server, I'm gonna change it and if I want to use a local server I will get back to your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="item item-select " id="findYourProject-select3">
  <span class="input-label">type of project</span>
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="topic in project_topics" value="{{topic}}">{{topic}}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

You want to repeat the `option`. Not the `select`.